# xCode - How to add 2 Default.png files in a single project?

Tags: xcode, default, targets

I have 2 different target in my project (full & light).
I also have different Default.png files (one for the full version and one for the light one).

Is it posible to include both files in the project (having different folders) and to exclude the other one from the target Bundle Resources?

For example to have:
TARGET FULL  to keep in Bundle only file Default.png from folder A
TARGET LIGHT to keep in Bundle only file Default.png from folder B

Or is any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the target to use a launch image not named `Default.png`. Set the `UILaunchImageFile` key in your `Info.plist` to the correct filename.

Comment: I believe this option is available since version 3.2. I need something for at least 3.1.3, if it's possible.